# Why does as.Date returns NA for a valid date?

Tags: r, date

The following code results in NA. Why?:

```
as.Date(paste(2015,53,1),"%Y %W %u")
```

The year 2015 had 53 weeks so the date should be totally fine.

Comment: What is your expected output? I think you need `%U` instead?

Answer (score 4):

From `?strptime`:

> %W
>   Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first
>   day of week (and typically with the first Monday of the year as day 1
>   of week 1). The UK convention.

The decimal number of the week of the year `%W` thus ranges from 0-53. Number one is considered to be the week with the first Monday. 2015 started with a Thursday (week 0). So there were 53 weeks in 2015, but the range of weeks went from 0 to 52, and not from 1 to 53.

```
> as.Date(paste(2015,0,1),"%Y %W %u")
[1] "2015-01-05"
> as.Date(paste(2015,52,1),"%Y %W %u")
[1] "2015-12-28"
```

Comment: Strange. 'as.Date(paste(2015,0,1),"%Y %W %u")' results in NA at my pc.

Comment: @Funkwecker I double-checked this. It works on my system, I cannot reproduce your NA result in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The weeks are actually counted 52 in 2015.

```
strftime(as.Date("2015-12-31"), "%W")
# [1] "52"
```

The remaining days are counted in 2016 as week 0.

```
strftime(as.Date("2016-01-01"), "%W")
# [1] "00"
```

For instance Jan, 1 of 2018 is in week 1 (because 2017 probably had 52 weeks).

```
strftime(as.Date("2018-01-01"), "%W")
# [1] "01"
```